# Chicken-egg with IntelliJ SVN ignoring rules

Tags: svn, android-studio, intellij-idea

The Android Studio I'm referring to is v 1.2.2

The `*.iml` files are not supposed to be a part of version control. I was not able to find official supporting link for this, but there're a few SO and Reddit threads supporting this; I tested myself to find that project can be started and built without these files.

The issue is that Android Studio constantly asks to add them to version control.  There's an *remember and don't ask again checkmark* available, also, *Version Control > Ignored Files* in settings does the same; this is the [officially supported solution](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/configuring-ignored-files.html).

The real problem is that this information is saved into `/.idea/workplace.xml` which itself is supposed to be ignored! (see generated `.gitignore`).

Is there any other persistent way?  I know that `svn:ignore` property is not making any effect on IntelliJ's version control client.

TIA.

Useful links:

[Is it mandatory to save *.iml files in Version control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25504982/is-it-mandatory-to-save-iml-files-in-version-control)

[Prevent IntelliJ from adding iml files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903859/prevent-intellij-from-adding-iml-files)

[Add ability to disable the feature to track obsolete svn:ignore](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-53306) (JetBrains bug tracker)

Comment: Is this an [tag:svn] or a [tag:git] question? You mentioned both `svn:ignore` and `.gitignore`...

Comment: @Roman, Subversion.  `.gitignore` is just mentioned as a reference as this is something IntelliJ generates on its own; assumed to be correct :)