# Remove .iml Files From GIT for Good

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea

I am having issues with the .iml files generated by Android Studio. On a Gradle sync, they are regenerated meaning I then have to do a commit even if nothing has changed. I just want to make these files untracked.

I have tried the following things.

- Added `*.iml` to my project's `.gitignore` file as well as each module's `.gitignore`. I have tried both `*.iml` and `**/*.iml`
- Used `git rm --cached app/app.iml` when they appear in the staged files list. Even after doing this and committing it, they appear as staged again later on.
- As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2903859/prevent-intellij-from-adding-iml-files) I added it to the Ignored Files in Settings under version control

Comment: /*/build/app.iml, *.iml,*.iml . Tried adding both to .gitingnore file?

Comment: @StuStirling Did you manage to solve this, if yes, how you did it?

Answer (score 44):

You have the right steps, but you need to organize them

1. `git rm --cached <all_your_iml_files>` to remove all of them from
   the remote repository.

   Alternatively you can do a simple command to delete all the `*.iml` files like
   `git ls-files | grep "\.iml$" | xargs git rm --cached`
2. Commit that change using `git commit -m "msg"` and after that, you can see all your `*.iml` files as untracked files.
3. Add `*.iml` to your **.gitignore** file and commit it in a separate commit or in the same previous commit.

Comment: I have done this multiple times. In fact I do this everytime they reappear but they are always re-staged

Comment: I just tried those steps on my terminal and they are working. Is the problem IDE related?

Comment: I believe it's when `gradle` runs a sync, it regenerates the `.iml` files and stages them in GIT regardless of steps I have taken to prevent it

Comment: It can't stage them if they are not in the remote repository and added to the .gitignore at the same time. It must edit the .gitignore to do so.

Comment: I just removed all my `.iml` files using `git rm --cached`, committed, pushed it to the remote repository's branch and then did a gradle sync and the .iml files were once again added to the staging...

Comment: I am having the same problem and this isn't working. Do I have to remove the file also from history?

Answer (score 11):

cd into project directory, git checkout and pull master branch

```
cd /home/your_user/project_directory
git checkout master
git pull origin master
```

edit `.gitignore` file to insert `*.iml`

```
git rm --cached **/*.iml
git commit -a -m "rm all *.iml, update .gitignore"
git push origin master
```

I was working on another maven & Java git project using Idea IDE and it seems to add *.iml in many of the child directories.

The glob syntax `**/*.iml` will cover all iml files in all directories within the current working directory.